# Extracting last word/text multiple matching logstash

Tags: regex, logstash

I have a Logstash pipeline for ingesting a whole file, multiline code used. I would like to get all matching events and extract only the last word or text. I can't get any regular expression working.

**File content**

```
some line extract this 875846 85746,857
some other line
some other line with more text
let's extract this 887362        24153,44737
some other final line
```

**Required match**

Finding all lines containing "extract this" and retrieve last word/text

**Expected output**

```
{
    "patternmatch1" => [
        [0] [
            [0] "85746,857"
        ],
        [1] [
            [0] "24153,44737"
        ]
    ],
       "@timestamp" => 2020-01-14T11:15:34.304Z
}
```

**Logstash pipeline**

```
input {
    file{
        path => "C:/file.txt"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => NUL
        codec => multiline { 
            pattern => "^nomatching"
            negate => true
            what => previous
            auto_flush_interval => 1
            multiline_tag => ""
        }
    }
}
filter {
  ruby { code => 'event.set("patternmatch1",event.get("message").scan(/extract this([^\r]*)/))' }
}
output {   
  stdout { codec => rubydebug } 
}
```

**The current output**

```
{
    "patternmatch1" => [],
     "message" => "some line extract this 875846 85746,857\r\nsome other line\r\nsome other line with more text\r\nlet's extract this 887362        24153,44737\r\nsome other final line\r\n\r",
   "@timestamp" => 2020-01-14T11:44:50.140Z
}
```

Comment: Use `/extract\s+this.*?(\d[\d,]*)$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much Wiktor but i got an empty patternmatch1 field output `{
    "patternmatch1" => [],
        "@timestamp" => 2020-01-14T11:35:01.720Z
}`. Maybe there is something wrong with the content of the file.

Comment: Even with `/extract +this.*?([0-9][0-9,]*)$/`? Just to rule out escaping. Try `/extract this.*?([0-9][0-9,]*) *$/`, too, to see if there are any trailing whitespace chars that interfere with matching.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, same behaviour

Comment: Try without `\s`. I updated the comment above.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Still empty, strange. Let me edit the post with message output.

Comment: So, yes, the culprit was the line endings, thanks for sharing my regex output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
/extract this.*?(\d[\d,]*)\r?$/
```

It will match

- `extract this` - literally
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(\d[\d,]*)` - Group 1 (what `scan` returns): a digit followed with 0+ digits or commas
- `\r?` - **an optional CR (carriage return)**
- `$` - end of a line.

Note that since the line endings in your file a CRLF, you can't match the end  of line position with a mere `$`, you should use `\r?$`.

Comment: Wow, it's working now. \r? do the job. Thank you so much, very apreciated.

Comment: @Vince Yes, you may also use something like `(?:[\r\n]|\z)` or `(?:\R|\z)` / `(?=\R|\z)`, but I prefer a non-alternation based patterns for performance reason.

Comment: thank you for this `you can't match the end of line position with a mere $, you should \r?$`.

Comment: @JBone Ah, sorry for the missing notional verb, added :)

Comment: :) No I was not highlighting that part. I actually did not know it is a better practice to use `\r?$` for end of the line.

Comment: @JBone That is just the consequence of the `$` matching in a multiline mode only before `\n` and not `\r` (that is on by default in Oniguruma/Onigmo regex engine). The same behavior is observed in .NET regex.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation